# DFA and equivalence relation

Tags: finite-automata

I was studying Theory of Computation and I'm kind of lost in solving this problem.

> Let $R$ be a relation defined on the set of states $Q$ of a DFA as $q_1Rq_2$ if $\delta(q_1,a)=\delta(q_2,a)$ for some $a\in\Sigma$.

> Is $R$ an equivalence relation? Prove.

So to prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation, I have to show that

- $R$ is reflexive
- $R$ is symmetric
- $R$ is transitive

But since it's related to DFA, I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Some help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why it makes any different that $R$ "is related to DFA". The point of mathematics is that it can model many different scenarios at once. An equivalence relation is an equivalence relation whether it comes from the world of set theory, from the world of automata theory, from measure theory, of from any other source.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. While `Theory of Computation` looks a title by *Use of Title Case*, you might name an author and/or include or hyperlink other information for identification, if not proper credit.

Answer (score 3):

Let me spell what $R$ being an equivalence relation means:

- Reflexivity: for all $q \in Q$ there exists $a \in \Sigma$ such that $\delta(q,a) = \delta(q,a)$.
- Symmetry: for all $q_1,q_2 \in Q$, if there exists $a \in \Sigma$ such that $\delta(q_1,a) = \delta(q_2,a)$ then there exists $b \in \Sigma$ such that $\delta(q_2,b) = \delta(q_1,b)$.
- Transitivity: for all $q_1,q_2,q_3 \in Q$, if there exist $a,b \in \Sigma$ such that $\delta(q_1,a) = \delta(q_2,a)$ and $\delta(q_2,b) = \delta(q_3,b)$ then there exists $c \in \Sigma$ such that $\delta(q_1,c) = \delta(q_3,c)$.

Now it's no longer about DFAs. It's about functions $\delta\colon Q\times\Sigma \to Q$.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I proceed from there?

Comment: If proving that $R$ is an equivalence relation, you should prove all of these properties. If giving a counterexample, you should design a function $\delta$ which fails to satisfy one of these three conditions.

Comment: I'm not going to solve this exercise for you, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No, that's not it. I'm kind of having trouble understanding all these state transitions

Comment: What you've answered is merely restating what I've said in the question, that is, the necessary properties R should follow to be an equivalence relation.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your source of difficulty. You should try (1) proving that $R$ is an equivalence relation or, (2) finding a counterexample. Sometimes, if you try to prove a claim and fail, then this points at a potential counterexample.

Comment: The function $\delta$ gets two inputs, $q \in Q$ and $a \in \Sigma$, and has one output, $\delta(q,a) \in Q$. Otherwise it is completely arbitrary. It's just a two-argument function.

Comment: So does this function only accepts q1 and q2? If that's the case, then how can I prove transitivity?

Comment: The function $\delta$ gets two inputs, $q \in Q$ and $a \in \Sigma$, and for each such two inputs it assigns an output in $Q$.

Answer (score -1):

To prove R is a equivalance relation then R must be reflexive,symmetric,transitive

1. Reflexive: for all q ∈ Q then there exists a ∈ Σ then δ(q,a)=δ(q,a).
2. Symmetric: for all q1,q2 ∈ Q, if then there exists a ∈  then δ(q1,a)=δ(q2,a) then there exists b∈Σ then δ(q2,b)=δ(q1,b).
   3.Transitive: for all q1,q2,q3 ∈ Q, if then  there exists a,b ∈ Σ then δ(q1,a)=δ(q2,a) and δ(q2,b)=δ(q3,b) then there exists c ∈ Σ then δ(q1,c)=δ(q3,c).
   hence R is Equivalance Relation.